# html-javascript- object array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I was creating a web page that prints the name of the most expensive book after receiving five book information via the prompt () function. But when I print the name of an expensive book, only the title of the first book is printed. Can you see why?

---

```
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Create array of book objects</title>
    <script>
      function Book(title, author, price) {
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.price = price;
      }

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h3>Create array of book objects</h3>
    <hr>
    <script>
      var i;
      var bookArray = new Array();
      var textSplit;

      for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var input = prompt("Enter book titles, authors, and prices, separated by commas.", "");
        textSplit = input.split(",");
        var book = new Object();
        book.title = textSplit[0];
        book.author = textSplit[1];
        book.price = parseInt(textSplit[2]);
        bookArray[i] = book;
      }

      for (i = 0; i < bookArray.length; i++) {
        document.write(bookArray[i].title + ", ");
        document.write(bookArray[i].author + ", ");
        document.write(bookArray[i].price + "<br>");
      }

      var most = bookArray[0];
      for (i = 0; i < bookArray.length; ++i) {
        if (bookArray[i].price > most) {
          most = bookArray[i].price;
        }

        // document.write(bookArray[i].title+"<br>");
      }
      document.write("<br> The most expensive book is " + most.title);

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first book is only getting printed because you are comparing Object to Number. You should use *.price* property of the object to compare and assign the object to *most*

```
var most = bookArray[0];
for(i=0; i<bookArray.length; ++i){
   if(bookArray[i].price > most.price){
     most = bookArray[i];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`var most` references your first book. In your loop, you compare the price to the object, not to the price of the object.

Try: `bookArray[i].price > most.price`

Answer (score 2):

Find the maximum number, then get that whole object which holds the max value, by doing this you can reduce the lines significantly.

```
 let max = Math.max(...bookArray.map(x => x.price))
 let maxBook = bookArray.find(x => x.price === max)
```

Here is the full code:  https://jsfiddle.net/chwoxv8q/

```
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Create array of book objects</title>
    <script>
      function Book(title, author, price) {
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.price = price;
      }

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h3>Create array of book objects</h3>
    <hr>
    <script>
      var i;
      var bookArray = new Array();
      var textSplit;

      for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var input = prompt("Enter book titles, authors, and prices, separated by commas.", "");
        textSplit = input.split(",");
        var book = new Object();
        book.title = textSplit[0];
        book.author = textSplit[1];
        book.price = parseInt(textSplit[2]);
        bookArray[i] = book;
      }

      var max = Math.max(...bookArray.map(x => x.price))
      var maxBook = bookArray.find(x => x.price === max)

      document.write("<br> The most expensive book is " + maxBook.title + maxBook.author);

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are only printing the title of the book, because your end print line is this :

```
document.write("<br> The most expensive book is " + most.title);
```

To display the title, author and price, do something more like this :

```
document.write("<br> The most expensive book is " + most.title + most.author+ most.price);
```

And about the page only displaying the first book, you should compare the price of the most object and not the object.

Answer (score 1):

in for loop you check if price is more than a Object `if(bookArray[i].price > most){...` that's wrong it's should be  `if(bookArray[i].price > most.price){...`. then you have to assign `most = bookArray[i]`;

Answer (score 1):

In the final loop you are comparing an object `most` to the price of the ith `bookarray` price. You are also assigning the `most` object to only the price instead of the ith `bookarray`

You just need to change these references as follows

```
 var most = bookArray[0];
  for(i = 0; i <bookArray.length; ++i)
  {
      if(bookArray[i].price > most.price)
         most = bookArray[i];
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` statement is misleading... The rest is okey:

```
if(bookArray[i].price > most){
  most = bookArray[i].price;
}
```

Use This:

```
if(bookArray[i].price > most.price){
  most = bookArray[i];
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Create array of book objects</title>
  <script>
    function Book(title, author, price) {
      this.title = title;
      this.author = author;
      this.price = price;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h3>Create array of book objects</h3>
  <hr>
  <script>
    var i;
    var bookArray = new Array();
    var textSplit;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      var input = prompt("Enter book titles, authors, and prices, separated by commas.", "");
      textSplit = input.split(",");
      var book = new Object();
      book.title = textSplit[0];
      book.author = textSplit[1];
      book.price = parseInt(textSplit[2]);
      bookArray[i] = book;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < bookArray.length; i++) {
      document.write(bookArray[i].title + ", ");
      document.write(bookArray[i].author + ", ");
      document.write(bookArray[i].price + "<br>");
    }

    var most = bookArray[0];

    for (i = 0; i < bookArray.length; ++i) {
      if (bookArray[i].price > most.price) {
        most = bookArray[i];
      }

      // document.write(bookArray[i].title+"<br>");
    }
    document.write("<br> The most expensive book is " + most.title + ", " + most.author + ", " + most.price);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```